# prepareForSegue Not Working with JSON Array - Swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, swift2

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate{

I have an empty Array:
 var articles = Article

i am pulling through the data through the URL and appending the array:
for (key, subJson) in json["Articles"] {

```
                let author = subJson["title"].string
                let subheading = subJson["subheading"].string
                let content = subJson["content"].string
                let Author = subJson["author"].string

                let stuff = Article(name: author!, subheading: subheading!, content: content!, author: Author!)


                    self.articles.append(stuff!)
```

I am trying to showcase the title in a tableview and then click on the cell to take the user to another view controller which will load some more information/data and images which are stored on the URL:

I am having issues with these 2 functions:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetailsView" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
        if let articles = sender as? Article {
            destination.ATsegue = articles
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("tapped")
    let article = articles[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailsView", sender: article)
}
```

}

I am not evening be able to view the print ("Tapped") on the console, so I'm assuming the code is not getting to the function. i need to be able to click the cell from the tableview controller and it will take me to the secondviewcontroller which displays data extracted from the URL

Does anyone know what to needs to be altered in order to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set tableView `delegate` and `dataSource`?

Comment: i did this: 
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

Comment: The formatting of your question is atrocious. It's not very time consuming to make sure your question is readable and it's the least you can do if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: add `UITableViewDelegate` and set it. Not data source

Comment: I have added the UITableViewDelegate and still no change

Comment: Could it be that there is a surplus `}` at the end of the `prepareForSegue` method?

Comment: i don't think so.. i have a old version of the application where i have manually added all of the content/data in the view controller, and used the exact same codes above, but obviously we cannot load data manually into the code. Just deleted it, and it came out with 5 errors... i don't think it was that :)